# How to connect to a remote SQL Server 2008 R2 instance using SSMS?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I want to connect to a remote SQL Server 2008 R2 instance installed on a remote Windows Web Server 2008, using SQL Server Management Studio Express. Can someone provide me all the necessary steps? I read some answers here, but nothing seems to work. I'm confused as to where (locally or remotely) to enable the SQL Browser, set TCP/IP ON, specify port 1499 etc.

Comment: if the below answer was any help, you should acknowledge it.

Comment: Yes sorry, I was sick so couldn't access internet these few days. And many thanks for the answer. It worked perfectly; however I also had to add an exception for sqlbrowser.exe and sqlservr.exe in the Windows Firewall on the Windows Web server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. enable **SQLBrowser**
2. open **1433** default port (in your case it may be different but **1433 is default**)
3. enable **SQL Server authentication** for your instance
4. **restart** your SQL Server instance
5. Make sure your domain (sql server instance) is **publicly/remotely accessible**
6. From SSMS enter your SQL Server instance **url/IP** address
7. enter your credentials

this should be all.